# setting Global variables or application values in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to assign a value as 0 by default, then every time that page is hit
I want to increase the value by one and when the value is 4 then I have to do some action on that page and change back the value of that variable to 0.

I want to you use global variables or application variables.
I don't want to use the database to save values. I tried my best to save the value in .env but read somewhere it's not the right way to do. Please guide me the best possible way? Working on Laravel 5.3

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to persist the value somewhere, whether it' in session, database, filesystem, cache storage, wherever.... what's your aversion to database?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file in the `config` folder and store the option there. For example, in a file named `system.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    "my_option" => 0,
];
```

Then you can have access to it calling `get` method from `Config`:

```
$myOption = \Config::get('system.my_option');
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can use session for this:

```
$counter = (int) session('counter', 0);

session(['error_pages' => ++$counter]);

if ($counter >= 4) {
  // here you do what you want
}
```

Of course in case you want to use this mechanism not in single user session you can use cookies to store counter value.

Comment: That would do for each session, but I guess he wants that behaviour to work across sessions...

Comment: Cookies are just a way to store sessions. It didn't change anything. @Laerte's approach involving storing values in a file in the server is more appropiate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the config function, is less overhead than use the session:

```
config(['shared_variable'=>$value])
```